# How to set what renders inside <ng-content> tags?

Tags: angular

I see a lot of articles about transclution, however there is a lot of solving imaginary problems in there. Could somebody tell me where one sets what should be generated in `<ng-content></ng-content>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Transclusion is a way of adding an HTML template to an angular component's template from outside of this component.*

An example will explain this concept far better than I do :

```
<custom-component>
  <!-- HTML template added to the custom-component's template through transclusion -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12>
      <p>My HTML template</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of the HTML template -->
</custom-component>
```

In order to make the transclusion work, as you pointed it out, you need to use **ng-content** tag. This tag indicates the location where Angular should render the outer HTML template in the component's template.

Imagine the following custom-component template :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <!-- Something -->
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

ng-content will be replace like this :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <!-- HTML template added to the custom-component's template through transclusion -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12>
          <p>My HTML template</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of the HTML template -->
    </section>
    <footer>
      <!-- Something -->
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

To answer your question, I would say that you can "set what renders inside ng-content tags" by adding some HTML inside the opening and closing tags of an angular component.